# Cant build app in terminal, only with AndroidStudio. (Ionic, cordova)

Tags: android-studio, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

I have an ionic, Cordova app, and it builds file in Android Stuio. But I can't build it in the terminal.

`ionic cordova build android --prod`

Leads to the following error:

```
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libsqlc-native-driver.so.

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'intermediateDir' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @OutputDirectory.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'intermediateDir'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'intermediateDir'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageNameXOR1' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'packageNameXOR1'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'packageNameXOR1'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageNameXOR2' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'packageNameXOR2'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'packageNameXOR2'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'quickstartFile' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @InputFile, @Optional.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'quickstartFile'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'quickstartFile'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'searchedLocation' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'searchedLocation'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'searchedLocation'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I assume some kind of configuration issue...
I know that the Grade versions is different in Android Studio.
But I don't know if that's the problem, and how to change it in the terminal build. See:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, for me, the following "config.xml" entry solved it:

GradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion 4.2.0 => 4.3.8:

```
<preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion" value="4.3.8" />
```